# Organising Google Apps Scripts themselves

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have build 3 "applications" in Google Sheets, all of them using various scripts for resetting the data and saving the data elsewhere. Each Sheet is associated with 2 or 3 scripts. However, in the Scripts folder I see a multitude of scripts. I would like to organise them e.g. in folders per application. Is there anyway of doing so?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to organize the scripts in the [Google Apps Script](https://scripts.google.com)'s dashboard page . However, you can also access them from [drive](https://drive.google.com). In Drive you can make folders and organize the Scripts, and they will still be accessible.

You can also submit a feature request from the Apps Script's dashboard page, located at the `?` button in the Send feedback option.

Comment: what do you mean 'In Drive you can make folders and organize the Scripts'? I see no my scripts anywhere on my Drive besides https://script.google.com/home (but there are no folders).

Comment: Same for me: I only see them under script.google.com. Is there a particular setting for Drive that is required?

Comment: I can see my scripts in My Drive root folder. I can see them from my normal account, also from my Google Workspace account. Try to search the script's project name in the Drive's search bar.

Comment: Jescanellas, are you using what was G Suite? Maybe there's a difference between "regular" gmail accounts and business accounts?

Comment: Yes, but I also tried different normal Gmail accounts, and I could see the scripts in all of them. In https://drive.google.com/drive/my-drive

Answer (score 0):

I figured out something crucial:

- Stand alone scripts CAN be accessed from Drive
  (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone)
- Those bound to a Sheet or Document can't (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound)

And, one needs to Connect Google Apps Scripts to Drive first:

1. Go to Google Drive and click New > More > Connect more apps.
2. When the "Connect apps to Drive" window appears, type "script" into
   the search box and press Enter.
3. Click Connect next to the listing for Google Apps Script. Now that
   you've connected the app, you can create a script by selecting New >
   More > Google Apps Script.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to locate App script project in google drive .

Steps :

Step 1 : Open Google drive .
Step 2 : Type in Google Appscript Project name in search bar and enter .
Step 3 : It will show all type of files with similar matching name .  You can Identify Google Appscript project by the icon . Locate that .
Step 4 : Click on three dots at the right side . You will find option "Organise " you can use to move your project in desired folder .

Done and Dusted !

Observations : There are no direct feature available on a standalone appscript project to view and organise its location as given in google Spreadsheet.
If it is a bound script then locating attached appscript is not a problem . However , if it is standalone  then it is important to organise it else  it is almost not trackable if you forget  name of  the project .